# Angular "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" with promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, es6-promise

I am stuck on why my promises aren't working. From the other articles I have looked at, I think I am doing it correctly. Here is the code I have currently:

**Factory code**

```
factory.isLoggedIn = function() {
  $http.get('/api/v1/fitbit/auth')
      .success((data) => {
           return data.status;
       })
       .error((error) => {
           console.log('Error: ' + error);
       });
}
```

**Controller code**

```
    $scope.fitbitAuth = function() {
        FitbitFactory.isLoggedIn()
            .then(
                function(data) {
                    $scope.fitbitStatus = data;
                },
                function(errorData) {
                    console.log(errorData);
                });
        return $scope.fitbitStatus;
    };
```

From my understanding of promises, the `return $scope.fitbitStatus` should be populating the `$scope.fitbitAuth`, but it isn't. I am also returning a boolean in the Factory, which should be populating `$scope.fitbitStatus`.

Comment: add return statement before $http in factory.isLoggedIn

Comment: and get rid of success and error in your factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `return` something (the promise), or it is `undefined`.

Factory code:

```
factory.isLoggedIn = function() {
  return $http.get('/api/v1/fitbit/auth');
}
```

Controller code:

```
$scope.fitbitAuth = function() {
    return FitbitFactory.isLoggedIn()
        .then(
            function(data) {
                $scope.fitbitStatus = data;
            },
            function(errorData) {
                console.log(errorData);
            });

};
```

The complete success/error block in your factory is not necessary and should be removed. I'm also unsure why you `return $scope.fitbitStatus;` as it is undefined at the time of return.

Edit: Edited the answer to actually return the promise.

Comment: I returned `$scope.fitbitStatus` because some of the other forums I was looking at recommended returning the promise. I may, and probably am, mistaken in how I implemented it though.

Comment: You are not returning a promise, but something that is undefined at the time you are returning. I edited the answer. @2b2a

Comment: @2b2a see where I moved the return in the controller code. Now the promise is returned. What you were returning will be undefined at the time you were returning

Answer (score 1):

Currently you haven't return anything from `isLoggedIn` factory method and you are calling `.then` method over it.

To make it working return `$http` promise`object from service method. In your case you could simply return`$http.get`method call which return promise object itself and then you can easily chain them up by calling`FitbitFactory.isLoggedIn().then`

```
factory.isLoggedIn = function() {
  return $http.get('/api/v1/fitbit/auth');
}
```